# Odoo 10 - Get sale order object for stock move line

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to get the corresponding sale order for stock move lines.
So for each delivery slip I will be able to provide information contained in the original sales order which motivated the stock move.

Is there any existing relation table that could be use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a connection between moves and sale lines:

```py
order = move.procurement_id.sale_line_id.order_id
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful, I am trying to understand Odoo data model. Why some stock_moves do have procurement_id populated and others don't?

Comment: Usually there will be procurements originating in sales or purchases or maybe orderpoints. Odoo will link these processes with each other. By creating a picking manually, you won't see any procurements on the linked moves. And a little hint for Odoo V11: model `procurement.order` was removed and as far as i know `procurment.group` will handle the connections now.